# How can I make a regular expression which finds the first inner pair words?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to make a regular expression which capture the first inner pair words. My code following works in a condition but it does not work in another. It captures the last pair words.

Please see the my code below.

```
def testReplaceBetweenWords():

    head_dlmt='Head'
    tail_dlmt='Tail'

    line0 = "abc_Head_def_Head_inner_inside_Tail_ghi_Tail_jkl"
    line1 = "abc_Head_first_Tail_ghi_Head_second_Tail_opq"

    between_pattern = "(^.*(?<={0}))(?!.*{0}).*?(?={1})(.*)$".format(head_dlmt, tail_dlmt)
    compiled_pattern = re.compile(between_pattern)

    # Case 0: good case: It captures the first inner words.    
    result0 = re.search(compiled_pattern, line0)  

    print("original 0    : {0}".format(result0.group(0)))
    print("expected Head : abc_Head_def_Head")
    print("found Head    : {0}".format(result0.group(1)))
    print("expected Tail :                                Tail_ghi_Tail_jkl")
    print("found Tail    : {0}{1}".format(' ' * (result0.regs[2][0]), result0.group(2)))

    print()

    # Case 1: Bad case: It captures the last pair words.    
    result1 = re.search(compiled_pattern, line1)

    print("original 1    : {0}".format(result1.group(0)))
    print("expected Head : abc_Head")
    print("found Head    : {0}".format(result1.group(1)))
    print("expected Tail :                Tail_ghi_Head_second_Tail_opq")
    print("found Tail    : {0}{1}".format(' ' * (result1.regs[2][0]), result1.group(2)))
```

And the outputs are following.

```
original 0    : abc_Head_def_Head_inner_inside_Tail_ghi_Tail_jkl
expected Head : abc_Head_def_Head
found Head    : abc_Head_def_Head
expected Tail :                                Tail_ghi_Tail_jkl
found Tail    :                                Tail_ghi_Tail_jkl

original 1    : abc_Head_first_Tail_ghi_Head_second_Tail_opq
expected Head : abc_Head
found Head    : abc_Head_first_Tail_ghi_Head
expected Tail :                Tail_ghi_Head_second_Tail_opq
found Tail    :                                     Tail_opq
```

The first case works well. It captures the first inner pair words.
The second case does not work. It captures the last pair words but I expected the first pair words.
How can I make a regular express which satisfies the two cases above?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
between_pattern = "^((?:(?!{1}).)*{0}).*?({1}.*)$".format(head_dlmt, tail_dlmt)
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/7NvpzK) and the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/L7VV2N/1).

**Details**

- The first `.*` pattern should be replace with a tempered greedy token `(?:(?!{1}).)*` that matches any 0+ chars that do not start the end delimiter character sequence (thus, you may up to the last `Head` that contains no `Tail`)
- There is no point using lookarounds inside capturing groups as these patterns will be part of those capturing groups

Note you may want to compile the regex with `re.S` flag to support strings with line breaks.

Comment: Stribizew: thank you for the solution. I will use your solution now. But let me ask you a little bit more. Can I use lazy quantifier with ?<=. That is,  it is like ^(.*?(?<={0})) ... .

Comment: @mora You really do not need that lookbehind as the text will still land in the capturing group.  Your `^(.*?(?<={0}))` is equal to `^(.*?{0})`, and yes you may use it if it delivers the expected result.

Comment: Stribizew; I had wandered ^(.*?(?<={0})) is equal to ^(.*?{0}) and I wanted to ask it. Thank you again for telling me it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be just match (*almost*) exactly what you want to match:

use this regex, and extract the first match:

```
(?<=Head)(?:(?!Head|Tail).)+(?=Tail)
```

in your case, use:

```
between_pattern = '(?<={0})(?:(?!{0}|{1}).)+(?={1})'.format(head_dlmt, tail_dlmt)
```

Even more: with this regex, you can extract the second, the third... the nth, just as easy as extract the first, and without any changes at all: it's more flexible.

see here:

> https://regex101.com/r/ds90y4/1/

Comment: @sieth.sh:thank you for your suggestion. I will use your suggestion when I will extract the words between head and tail delimiter.